# How to calculate the determinant of this matrix (Hessian matrix + Identity)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying that in order to calculate the volume under a graph of a function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ the Area element we should integrate is $$ \sqrt{1+\left|\nabla\phi\left(x\right)\right|^{2}} $$
(over the set we want to calcualte the volume on).

All I have left to do right now is to calculate the determinant of $$ \begin{bmatrix}1+\left(\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{1}}\right)^{2} & \frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{1}}\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{2}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{1}}\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{k}}\\
\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{1}} & 1+\left(\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{2}}\right)^{2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{k}}\\
\vdots\\
\\
\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{k}}\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{1}} & \cdots &  & 1+\left(\frac{\partial\phi\left(x\right)}{\partial x_{k}}\right)^{2}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Which should be $$ 1+\left|\nabla\phi\left(x\right)\right|^{2} $$

And Im done.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a $k\times k$ square matrix, why would you get $1+(\frac{\partial\phi(x)}{\partial x_j})^2$ as the determinant?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Sorry, typo. Fixed

Comment: Apply $\det(I+xy^T)=1+y^Tx$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks!